# How to change bluetooth discoverable icon in my app

Tags: android, bluetooth, imageview, android-bluetooth

I am working with a bluetooth app. It has own icon to notify whether device bluetooth is discoverable or not. I want to set an image when it is discoverable and set another image when it is not discoverable. It is easy to do using thread or handler or etc. But my problem is that if any body change the discoverable options using system then how can it detect and change my discoverable image?

Comment: you wanna listen the state of  bluetooth ,means is discoverable or not  right ?

Answer (score 1):

First you wanna listen bluetooth state and next you can change the icon wherver you want please put the needed permissions too

```
public class BluetoothConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public BluetoothConnectionReceiver(){
    //No initialisation code needed
}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action.getAction()){
        //Do something with bluetooth device connection
    } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action.getAction()){
        //Do something with bluetooth device disconnection
    }
}
```

}

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

<application ...>
    ...
    <receiver
        android:name="..."
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.ACL_CONNECTED/>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```